# Ruby on rails activate record condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to specify and OR condition?

For example:

```
Message.find(1, :condition => {"profile_id = ? OR sender_id = ?", 2, 2})
```

Ultimately, I want to check whether a user has sent or received a message, but if I do them separate I an exception is thrown when the record is not found for one of the cases.

Comment: Replace the `{}` with `[]` and `:condition` with `:conditions` and I think you've got your OR. I suspect that's just a typo, though. Is there a part to this question that I missed?

Comment: Awesome that worked fine. It wasn't a typo I though it was an options hash? Thank you!

Comment: The options hash is also available, but it defaults to an 'AND' operation. Using :condition => {:key_one => val_one, :key_two => val_two} will find only elements matching both keys.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! Change the {}s to []s and

```
Message.find(:first, :condition => ["profile_id = ? OR sender_id = ?", profile_id, sender_id])
```

should do it for you.

(By the way, don't forget that it's also always possible to just use find_by_sql in case there's not a 'clever enough' helper current available...)